# NPM failing to install because of UNC path

Tags: python, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am on Windows 2019 server I need to execute the command here

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

This command in turn needs to run npm to download some files. The error below is very clear the command can not call a UNC path. The error is understood but what do I do to have it go to the local path instead.

```
Node v16.14.2

Yarn configuration loaded.
Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
> node \\SERVERNAME\E$\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js install --non-interactive
'\\SERVERNAME\E$\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\atoti\share\jupyter\lab\staging'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
yarn install v1.21.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 0.05s.
```

Some context I am running this in powershell inside my python active environment.
My profile was setup to my python environment that used the UNC path I believe that's how it got there. I installed all components under that setting
I have gone back and changed my powershell profile to use local path to environment and I have started a new powershell session with new profile settings. So my question is how do I have the node command use the Local path instead of the UNC path?